# how to stay on same route in vuejs after page reload when running vuejs project in dev mode on some port?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this two routes in `router.ts`:

```
export default new Router({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
        { path: "/", component: require("./components/dashboard/Dashboard.vue")},
        { path: "/counter", component: require("./components/counter/Counter.vue") }
    ],
});
```

`Vue.use((Router) as any);`

Now when i go to http://localhost:5000/counter directly in browser i got "/" route? Same happens on page reload. If I go to counter like this:

```
<router-link to="/counter">Counter</router-link>
```

and then do reload, i dont see `counter` page anymore but default route.
This is on localhost, so no nginx and so on, are involved, as it is explained here: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: Is this even possible? Or this is natural behaviour of vujes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though, it shouldn't happen but I think the `exact` property in vue-router could help you, try:

```
<router-link to="/counter" exact>Counter</router-link>
```

Comment: same thing. just goes to "/" on refresh or when you enter url directly.

Comment: maybe something is wired in my project. i need to debug further.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing your router instance to vue? how is your main.js or routes.js (if any looks like?)

Comment: Vue.use((Router) as any);

Comment: It is usually VueRouter but pretty much.

Comment: It is just `import Router from "vue-router";` So does not matter what name I use.

Comment: Can you just use `Vue.use(Router)`? I'm not familar with that import code

Comment: btw:, when I said passing the router to vue instance, I meant if you are passing it to `new Vue({  router: router})`

Comment: I found problems with some requireAuth stuff on routes. Wired. Thanks for the help.